# Clustering user's based on multiple variables

Tags: algorithm, statistics, cluster-analysis

I have a website and I collect a lot of logs on user behavior. What time they log in, what products they look at, how often they look at it, etc. I want to see if I can do cluster analysis based on this but I'm not sure how to incorporate the multiple variables.

Specifically my problem is with how to weight their importance and cluster different groups when different variables are more important to different groups. For example, I understand those who look at the same products can be grouped but there's also a percentage of users who log in to purchase the products because of their job and they tend to log in at the same time every week or month so for them I think consistency of purchasing time would be important.

I'm weak at stats but I'm determined to learn - where can I learn how to approach this problem? I have been looking at k-mean, and neural networks but haven't had a clear idea of how to implement it to this problem.

Comment: Is it a possibility for you to get an expert manually tag some of the users, and determine their "type"? If so, you will be able to tag just a small portion of them manually, and used a supervised algorithm to classify the majority of them.

Comment: @amit ideally I would like to use a unsupervised approached to provide me with groups that I did not think of.

Comment: k-means?? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

Comment: check [deterministic annealing for clustering](http://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/11811863.pdf), http://thesis.library.caltech.edu/2858/

Comment: @NikosM. Thank you i'll look at those links.  I thought K-mean is either 2 items or I would have to square the sums of all other variables(therefore making every variable equal weighted).

Comment: no k-means can cluster the data to as many clusters you define, but you have to define number of clusters and it does not have to be two that is why it is `k`-means and not 2-means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Okay this answer turned out to be longer than planned, but this is a nice refresher for myself:*

Here I assume many things, e.g. that

- the duration of a site visit is short (minutes).
- each user is concerned only with a single task
- You consider each session as a black-box transaction.

You should create your own new attributes from the dataset. If necessary, create a bunch of attributes such as "logs_in_on_workdays", "logs_in_on_weekend", "logs_in_morning", "logs_in_afternoon", "session_duration_minutes", "logs_out" etc. - this is based on the date values.

Can't say much about your items. What about "looks_at_dairyprod", "looks_at_softdrinks"...?

Maybe you can also use the user_agent field  "browser_type", "os_name", "is_mobile" etc. maybe "is_authenticated", remote_host_type ("is_bot") etc 
- Whatever your log files allow.

Maybe you can join your authenticated users with other datasets to create even more attributes such as "is_male", "is_employee" etc etc.

This data wrangling part of your project will certainly be a lot of fun.
The end result will be a big table with numeric values, most 1-or-0 values.

If you include other numeric attributes, such as "Age", "duration", These data should be normalized to values between 0 and 1.

Then   you can run cluster analyses, with kmeans algorithm, parameterized with, say, *k* = 10, 11, 12... 20 .

Your definitive choice of a reasonable value of *k* depends on *your* requirements (how many clusters do you *want* to find? What expectation do you have about outliers? For example,  for `k =5`, Would it be meaningful to find 1 cluster with say 36000 users, and 4 clusters with 100 users each? Then you should increase the number of clusters and hope that the big one will be split)

Your cluster assignments must be joined back to the original dataset-table *myview*. Then you do cross-tabulation. In R, You do this by running commands like this:

`(clust2 <- data.frame(sapply(colnames(myview),function(x){
         tapply(myview[,x], km20$clusternum, mean)
 })))`

The resulting table (example below, for `k=20`) will give you *hints* about on how your data is structured, but not a definitive answer.

However, processing the results from your kmeans-clustering, you can answer questions like

*Which cluster(s) best fits the description “periodic site visits taken by authenticated users on weekday mornings”?*

```
## ClusNo Duration Morning Afternoon Periodic Weekd Authenticated   Age
## 1     840.0  0.0000    0.0000  1.0000  0.9510 0.0000 48.49
## 2    9335.3  0.3515    0.4485  0.1576  0.6333 0.6333 00.00
## 3     744.7  0.0000    0.8410  0.0000  0.0000 1.0000 28.01
## 4     621.4  1.0000    0.0000  0.0000  0.9975 1.0000 50.14
## 5     617.1  0.0000    0.9871  0.0000  1.0000 1.0000 40.34
## 6     844.8  0.0000    0.9641  0.0000  0.0000 0.9648 49.72
## 7     689.1  0.0000    0.0000  1.0000  0.9941 1.0000 46.77
## 8     729.4  1.0000    0.0000  0.0000  0.9935 0.0000 48.79
## 9     680.7  0.0000    0.9817  0.0000  1.0000 1.0000 54.81
## 10    734.6  0.0000    0.0000  1.0000  0.0000 0.7328 30.73
## 11    586.0  1.0000    0.0000  0.0000  1.0000 1.0000 30.18
## 12    772.1  0.0000    0.0000  1.0000  1.0000 0.0000 28.20
## 13    673.8  0.0000    0.0000  1.0000  1.0000 1.0000 28.37
## 14    646.4  0.0000    0.9226  0.0000  1.0000 1.0000 27.16
## 15    876.1  0.0000    0.9331  0.0000  0.0000 0.0000 32.37
## 16    687.5  1.0000    0.0000  0.0000  1.0000 0.0000 28.93
## 17    767.7  0.0000    0.9900  0.0000  1.0000 0.0000 49.33
## 18    748.6  1.0000    0.0000  0.0000  0.0000 0.6540 34.10
## 19    738.6  0.0000    0.9503  0.0000  1.0000 0.0000 29.03
## 20  45891.4  0.2020    0.1212  0.5758  0.8586 0.7273 00.00
```

*Which clusters can be described as “shorter than average visits (< n minutes) that occur on weekday evenings”?*

and many,many more. You must use business knowlege to choose interesting attributes and to ask the right questions.

Maybe you find overlooked clusters,or hints about the response variable of interest of your clusters (here, age). This is what basic cluster-analysis gives you.

Answer (score 1):

I read somewhere that k-means clustering is affected by outliers, hence PAM ( partition around medoids ) clustering is a better  alternative.[Source](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/cluster/html/pam.html)